# Javascript nested object

Tags: javascript

Considering this following javascript object below:

Object

```
{
    _id: "553ea677da00122e5413d8c2",
    {
        "labyname": "Mq",
        "data": [
            [
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
            ],
            [
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
            ], null, null, null, null, "Mq"]
    }: ""
}
```

---

**To access id in that object I can do something like that:**

`var=object[0]["_id"]`

***Can anyone tell me how to access "`labyname`" and "`data`?***

Comment: unfortunately what you posted isn't a valid object structure. There's either an extra set of `{}` after `_id` or a missing property name. Similar problem at the end. Need a clean and complete structure in order to assist

Comment: This is a maze value I am retrieving from a mongodb database. I get the value, I can access id, but before I wrote object["labyname"]["data"] it does not work

Comment: `data` and `labname` are properties on the same level

Comment: @charlietfl Unfortunately it might be valid JSON. See my answer as to how...but not why cause I have no idea why you would ever do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is very wrong with this object. It looks like what you have is an object with two properties: `_id` and then a JSON string that has an empty string for a value. If that is what you truly have (may the coding gods have mercy on your algorithms) then you would need to get the second key by filtering out the `_id` and then parsing the other key into an object. Something like:

```
var json = Object.keys(your_crazy_object).filter(function (key) { return key !== '_id'; })[0];
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj.labyname); // "Mq"
console.log(obj.data); // [[[1,1,1,...,1,1,1]], [[1,1,1,...,1,1,1]], null, null, null, null, "Mq"]
```

Comment: this is truly what I find from mongodb collection. By the way, I will try your code and will tell you if I succeed!

Comment: If this is the issue you might want to check the function that is saving the document in that form.

Comment: @AndreFauhlt I'm curious if that was the issue. Any updates?

Comment: Thank's for for the trial. But nothing works. httpresponse is the variable that returns those nested object. I did something like this instead in the following line: 

var json = Object.keys(your_crazy_object).filter(function (key) { return key !== '_id'; })[0];
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj.labyname); 
console.log(obj.data);

Unfortunately, it displays "undefined"

Comment: Can I put httpresponse between the parenthesis instead of "your-crazy_object)?

Comment: I modify something from the function by using the right variable name; as a resutl: IT WORKS!!! Thank you!!!!

Comment: `your-crazy_object` was meant to be whatever the object you included in your question. It's just a variable but should be set to the object in question.

Comment: Yes! it works! Unfortunately I cannot vote up for you!